# query on array value in moralis where the array contains objects

Tags: moralis

I was reading on how to query in moralis because I have to use something like that however, the docs does not seem to explain what I intend to do and I have been there for close to 2hrs and I seem to catch nothing to use

so my query is suppose to be close to the domo https://v1docs.moralis.io/moralis-dapp/database/queries#queries-on-array-values except in their case the array contained only  number in my case it is an array of many objects like this

```
{
"name":"some name",
"attributes": [
    {
        "trait_type": "Background",
        "value": "Aquamarine",
        "rarityScore": 7.912183544303797
    },
    {
        "trait_type": "Fur",
        "value": "Gray",
        "rarityScore": 20.163306451612904
    },
    {
        "trait_type": "Clothes",
        "value": "Pimp Coat",
        "rarityScore": 125.0125
    },
    {
        "trait_type": "Mouth",
        "value": "Bored Unshaven Dagger",
        "rarityScore": 357.1785714285714
    },
    {
        "trait_type": "Eyes",
        "value": "Closed",
        "rarityScore": 14.105782792665725
    },
    {
        "trait_type": "Hat",
        "value": "Bayc Hat Black",
        "rarityScore": 43.864035087719294
    },
    {
        "trait_type": "TraitCount",
        "value": 6,
        "rarityScore": 15.04192517390487
    },
    {
        "trait_type": "Earring",
        "value": null,
        "rarityScore": 1.4236298932384341
    }
],
}
```

so what am doing is, my query should filter the objects on `attributes` where i supply `trait_type` and `value`

I tried

```
query.equalTo("attributes", filterQuery);
```

but it does not work coz in my case `filterQuery` is an array with different objects each with unique `trait_type`  and `value`

and example of `filterQuery` am using is

```
 [
    {
        "trait_type": "Fur",
        "value": "Blue"
    }
]
```

will appreciate very much if someone can help me solve this or even an idea on how it is done

Answer (score 1):

Hi if `attributes` is a column of `array` with an array of objects value:

```
[
    {
        "trait_type": "Background",
        "value": "Aquamarine",
        "rarityScore": 7.912183544303797
    },
    {
        "trait_type": "Fur",
        "value": "Gray",
        "rarityScore": 20.163306451612904
    },
    {
        "trait_type": "Clothes",
        "value": "Pimp Coat",
        "rarityScore": 125.0125
    },
    {
        "trait_type": "Mouth",
        "value": "Bored Unshaven Dagger",
        "rarityScore": 357.1785714285714
    },
    {
        "trait_type": "Eyes",
        "value": "Closed",
        "rarityScore": 14.105782792665725
    },
    {
        "trait_type": "Hat",
        "value": "Bayc Hat Black",
        "rarityScore": 43.864035087719294
    },
    {
        "trait_type": "TraitCount",
        "value": 6,
        "rarityScore": 15.04192517390487
    },
    {
        "trait_type": "Earring",
        "value": null,
        "rarityScore": 1.4236298932384341
    }
]
```

Based on your `filterQuery` example, you could do something like:

```
query.equalTo("attributes.trait_type", "Fur");
query.equalTo("attributes.value", "Blue");
```

Which will only return an Object that has that particular trait_type and value combination in its `attributes`.

If the value of attributes is like the example you posted that has `"name":"some name"`, you would use (again for a column name of `attributes`):

```
query.equalTo("attributes.attributes.trait_type", "Fur");
query.equalTo("attributes.attributes.value", "Blue");
```

If you have more questions or issues with this, please post on either:

- Moralis Discord: https://moralis.io/joindiscord
- Moralis forum: https://forum.moralis.io

Comment: Hello @Alex this works for one trait for instance in the one above "Fur" what if am trying to filter from more than one trait?

Comment: You can just add another set of `query.equalTo` constraints for that additional trait_type/value.